# how to write inner join query in DQL(DOCTRINE) for select inside select

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine, dql

i want to write this SQL query in DQL (DOCTRINE)

```
select <cols> from profile INNER JOIN (
 SELECT <primary key cols> FROM PROFILES
WHERE x.sex='M' ORDER BY rating LIMIT 100000,10
) AS x USING (<primary key cols>);
```

Hey guys please help me

any help will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: i think subquery is not allowed in DQL

Comment: subqueries are ok but a join in doctrine means a relation in the model, so this never worls

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are not currently supported within the `FROM` clause in [DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#ebnf).